# Appcelerator - Image from Camera gets rotated to 90 degree for Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, appcelerator, screen-orientation

I'm trying to take image from camera and then post it to my server for Android.The problem is when I take image it gets rotated to 90 degree. I tried different solutions but I didn't meet success.I tried to capture the orientation of screen in which camera was open so that I can rotate ImageView, but it didn't work.

If anyone faced this problem and knows the solution, please help. I would be grateful.

Android SD : 5.2.0, Testing Device : Samsung A700FD, OS : 5.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, but there is a workaround with this module:

https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/AndroidRotateImage

"There's a annoying, yet somewhat rare issue when taking photos with certain Andorid devices, where the orientation information is not properlly identified by Titanium, causing a photo taken in portrait format to be returned as landscape.

[...]

Besides rotating the image, the library scales the image to the specified width, and compresses it to the specified percentage. This is particulary useful, since Android camera images can be huge and could potentially make your device run out-of-memory."

Comment: I tried the other image rotating modules available for Appcelerator and this one was the only one that consistently worked. I noticed that the newer Samsung phones seem to suffer from this issue (Note 5, S7's, etc...). Also note, if you're trying to flip any thumbnails generated by Android, this won't work. They have their orientation flags stripped. I ended up creating my own thumbnails from the original images.